# when validating at w3c it is not recognizing the alt attribute when echo php $image

Tags: php, html, validation

I have an page for viewing posters with the following code:

```
<div class="img"><img src="<?= $image; ?>" alt="" /></div>
```

but when I validate it at w3c it could not find the alt attribute. 
maybe I have to escape the PHP element in someway?

How could I do that?

The error I get:

> An img element must have an alt attribute, except under certain
>   conditions. For details, consult guidance on providing text
>   alternatives for images.

Comment: What does the generated `HTML` look like?

Comment: …"><img src="img/flyers/flyerbl3.jpg" /></div></a></li><li><a class="fancybox" …

Comment: You can clearly see from the generated HTML that there is no alt tag.

Comment: var_dump or echo out the $image var on its own, and show us what is currently assigned to it.  if the $image value contains a double quote `"` it could be breaking the HTML

Comment: `alt` is an attribute, not a tag.

Comment: @AhmedNuaman if you look at my question you see that i added an alt=""

Comment: Doesn't matter - the attribute isn't there in the generated HTML. Something is messing with your PHP output.

Comment: when i do a var_dump i get this: string(23) "img/flyers/flyerbl2.jpg"

Comment: what is output line 1 or before <html>?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. i had 2 times `<ul id="grid">` on the same page. i still don't know why the error for the alt attribute appeared but when i edited the second id to grid2 the page was passed with 0 errors.

Thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score -2):

I've never seen `<?=` before, so I would think your problem is that the PHP isn't being executed and the `<` and/or `>` is messing up the validator's parsing. If `<?=` is valid, or if you're validating by file upload or direct input, then I definitely think the problem is the arrows messing up the validator's parsing.

Also, just doing `$image;` won't output the value of the variable, you need to use `echo` as well.

Comment: `<?=` is just short hand PHP for `<?php echo`

Comment: <?= is the shortag of <?php echo.

Comment: `<?=` is a PHP valid short tag for `<?php echo` but it must be turned on in php.ini

Comment: the shortag works because i include header and footer using <?= include('header'); ?> and that works. so the shorttag is allowed.